# network utilization in windows task manager

Tags: home-networking, task-manager

Ok I don't really get why or how the way this graph and the columns are labeled.

Link speed shows 1Gbps
graph only shows from 0% to 5%
and network Utilization stays on average around 1.25%

Ok I guess my first question is, why does my graph only shows from 0-5%?
2nd question, what does 1.25% network Utilization mean? Is it out of 100%? If it's % why is it 1.25 and not .125?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#1**

The graph scale change according to the utilization.

For example, if your utilization constantly stay below 1%, then it will top at 1%. When your utilization jump to 12%, the graph will top at 20% or 25% etc.

**#2**

1.25% means 0.0125. So 1.25% of 1Gbps link speed == 1Gbps(1024Mbps) x 0.0125 == 12.8Mbps